# What is it called when an operator is composed with a second operator and its inverse ($H^{-1} \circ T \circ H$)? What are some examples?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

A student of mine recently came up with a programming solution that is an instance of $H^{-1} \circ T \circ H$, where $T$ is a translation and $H$ and $H^{-1}$ are roughly an embedding/projection pair.  (The embedding and projection are not exact because in this example $T$'s domain and codomain are different.)

I'm pretty sure I've seen examples like this before, especially when $T$'s domain and codomain are equal.  Maybe in quantum mechanics?  But I have not been able to find any examples, and I have not been able to recall the name of this transformation, in which $H$ and its inverse are used to modify $T$.

Where can I find examples of this transformation?  And perhaps learn what the transformation is called?

Comment: conjugation or similarity transform.

Comment: @Norman If $T$ and $H$ are thought of as linear transformations (via [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations)), then the operation $T \mapsto H^{-1}TH$ is a [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis)

Comment: @Norman It is a bit strange that $H$ and $H^{-1}$ are an "embedding/projection pair" since embeddings and projections are not "invertible" in the usual sense of the term. Then again, the word "roughly" might be doing some heavy lifting there.

Comment: @BenGrossmann very heavy lifting.  With a usual embedding and projection $H^{-1} \circ H$ is the identity function and $H \circ H^{-1}$ is a partial, idempotent function (often but not always the identity on the set on which it is defined).  That's the situation I'm asking about.  My student's code is more complicated because there's a translation stuck in the middle.  I haven't worked out the math---in part because I want to find those simpler examples.

Comment: @Norman In that case, you have deviated from the strict meaning of the term "inverse". In most mathematical contexts, $H$ is only called "invertible" if we can find a map $H^{-1}$ for which $H^{-1} \circ H$ **and** $H \circ H^{-1}$ are the identity function. Your operation looks more to me like a [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_(functional_analysis)#:~:text=is%20the%20orthogonal%20projection%20onto,K%20sending%20k%20to%20Tk.) than a change of basis.

Comment: @Norman Note that if $T$ is a matrix and we have
$$
H = \pmatrix{I_m\\ 0}
$$
($I_m$ being the size-$m$ identity matrix), then $H^\top T H$ is the leading principal submatrix of $T$. Perhaps this is the kind of example that you're looking for

Comment: @BenGrossmann If  I remember my math these functions might be called half-inverses.  But it has been 38 years.  The embedding is invertible and total on its domain.  The projection is its inverse.  The projection is partial.

Comment: It's possible I should not have used the linear-algebra tag.  I wasn't sure how to tag the question.

Comment: @Norman Maybe this kind of thing comes up in the context of unbounded operators, where it's common to use partial functions. We might have a better idea of the kind of thing you're looking for if you said a bit more about that programming solution. For instance, what do the domain/codomain look like in this case?

Comment: @BenGrossmann The code is part of a compiler.  $H$ embeds a source-language closure into a source-language expression; $T$ translates a source-language expression into a target-language expression, and $H^{-1}$ projects a target-language expression (or dies trying).  $H$ and $T$ are total; $H^{-1}$ is partial, and the image of the codomain of $H$ under $T$ is completely contained in the domain of $H^{-1}$.  So although $H^{-1}$ is not a total function, $H^{-1} \circ T \circ H$ is a total function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) of $T$ by $H$. It’s a general abstract algebra concept that works in any group. An example from linear algebra is [matrix similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity), which can function as a [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis).